# keep int specific length in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am wanting to make sure that all values within my column (`accountNumber`) are exactly 7 characters long. I have tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `accountNumber` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  ...

  CHECK (accountNumber >6),
  CHECK (accountNumber <8),
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But when I enter a value other than 7 charachters long into the database it allows it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a trigger! (Since it's MySQL.)

Comment: I think this will check the value of the field not the length, fo you can check if its >999999 and <10000000

Comment: @54l3d tried that and still allowing me to edit and insert number of different sizes!

Comment: @Maximilian plz check this link [check constraint does not work?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9668)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert_account
     BEFORE INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.accountNumber < 1000000 OR NEW.accountNumber > 9999999
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only 7 digit integers allowed';
          END IF;
     END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_update_account
     BEFORE UPDATE ON account FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.accountNumber < 1000000 OR NEW.accountNumber > 9999999
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only 7 digit integers allowed';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```

If your MySQL database doesn't support `SIGNAL`, you can use `CALL` instead like this:

```
CALL `'Cannot add or update row: only 7 digit integers allowed'`;
```

Note: this code isn't tested, it's just to show the concept.